# How can I calculate the voltage over a microphone?

Tags: arduino, microphone

I want to make a microphone myself with the Arduino (capsule=microphone):

[image]

I have bought the following as  [microphone](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1660938.pdf):

As is in the datasheet the microphone operating voltage is between 1.5 and 10 volts. The problem is how do I calculate what resistor do I use to get that voltage? I can't use it as a voltage divider (the resistor with the microphone) right?

P.S. I have resistors laying around between 10 \$ \Omega \$ until 10 M\$ \Omega \$ so that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 1 hints at the value - it says output impedance is 2k2 and, given that the internal transistor is a JFET and, JFETs tend to have output impedances in the 10k+ range, it can be assumed that the 2k2 is the value of the resistor needed to power the circuit.

It'll be no problem with 2k2 but, don't forget to apply a very clean supply to the device - if you use 5V then filter it with a 1kohm and 10uF RC filter before connecting the mike via the 2k2.

Of note is the microphone current specified at a maximum value of 0.5mA - this is a guarantee that the microphone won't consume anything greater than 0.5 mA under quiescent conditions.

Comment: Good point about the RC filter! SO the 2.2k can be used as the resistor and then for example I can do 5=10*((2200)/(2200+x)) and with some rewriting x becomes 8800 ohm? The 5 is the voltage that I want to be on the microphone and 10 is the input V+. Is this 8800 correct. This is apart from the filter, but just to make it easier for myself to understand right now

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding what x is or what the "10" is? I'm guess the 5 means 5 volts but why the calculation at all?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to make a new alinea, but that made the message go online already

Comment: The calculation is there, because part of the voltage drops over the resistor and part of it goes over the microphone. So I need to calculate the resistor to make sure that the voltage over the microphone is in between the 1.5 and 10 volts. Is this correct?

Comment: No that's incorrect. the microphone will always consume a bit less than 0.5mA in all situations when the voltage applied to the 2k2 is between 1.5 volts and 10V. Microphone specs tend to be unclear on this and your spec is just a one sheet document and is particularly bad at conveying this information!!

Comment: Without looking at heat the current consumption is less, but stays the same when on one voltage? Then what current can be assumed? 0.4 mA or 0.3 or even lower?

Comment: There isn't enough information to make that estimate - all I know is that a JFET amp inside a mike will be roughly taking a constant current over a fairly wide supply range. But 0.5mA is worst case and if this flows through a 2k2 resistor the volts on the mike is 10V - 2k2*0.5mA = 8.9 volts and power dissipation is under 5 milli watts so is there a problem with 5 mW dissipated by the mike?

Comment: I don't thinks so, but let's say I want to measure the decibels using this microphone. It can only give me voltage that changes so the decision is based on the voltage measured from the ground and the output, but are you saying that it is hard to calculate that without more information?

Comment: The DC voltage appearing at the junction is just the quiescent voltage and has nothing to do with the superimposed AC signal that represents the waveform of the sound being received by the diaphragm of the mike. If you looked at the voltage waveform that rides on the DC level you can use the microphone sensitivity to calculate what the sound pressure level is.

Comment: Say you see 8.9 mV RMS AC on the output - that corresponds to a sound pressure wave of 1 pa RMS on the diaphragm. 1 Pa = 94 dB SPL.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. Ok I understand it now a little bit more. So in general the resistor is not that important. If I would choose a 2k resistor I would be just fine?

Comment: Yes you should be OK but the sensitivity of the microphone would be reduced by 10% for a resistor that is 10% lower.

Comment: Do you have some kind of calculation for that? That sounds right, but calculation can come in handy also for in the future

Comment: The spec says it has a sensitivity of -41 dBV/Pa at 1kHz. -41dBV = 8.9mV RMS so 8.9 mV is produced by 1Pa. 1Pa = 94 dB SPL.

Comment: I meant like with the 10% lower sensitivity. How do you calculate that?

Comment: The output signal voltage of the JFET is determined largely by the impedance in the drain i.e. gain is proportional to that resistor value. When biased correctly gate voltage rising and falling produces a drain current that rises and falls. That rising and falling drain current gets converted to a voltage by the resistor.

Comment: If I would go above the resistor value of the microphone would that still be true? (I don't know that much about JFETS, so maybe a noob quuestion :) ). BTW, your help is incredible by understanding all the concepts!

Comment: You can increase the 2k2 and get more "amplification" but beyond a certain point the high frequencies would start to be eroded and the flatness of the spectrum would deteriorate. I'm going to have to bring comments to a close on this question because we've gone beyond the scope of the orignal question. If you have more to ask, please raise a new question.

Comment: If you think you've got good value from this answer, please consider marking it as "accepted".